# Laravel exceptions outputs to console

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.4

I have an issue with my Laravel setup, that whenever i call an artisan command that throws an exception that when is caught is shown as output before whatever i have in my catch block executes.

Which results in easily gigabytes of log files and/or incredibly slow execution as it have to write gigabytes worth of text to console.

It used to be working fine, and i haven't done any major updates since it last worked.

Setup:
PHP 7.1
Laravel 5.4

Part of generic output:

```
removed
(1/1) February
removed
(1/1) February
removed
(1/1) February
removed
(1/1) February
removed
(1/1) February
object(ErrorException)#4587 (8) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(40) "Creating default object from empty value"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(69) "/home/kim/www_reports/app/Console/Commands/removed.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(107)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(23) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(69) "/home/kim/www_reports/app/Console/Commands/removed.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(107)
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "handleError"
      ["class"]=>
      string(48) "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(5) {
        [0]=>
        int(2)
        [1]=>
        string(40) "Creating default object from empty value"
        [2]=>
        string(69) "/home/kim/www_reports/app/Console/Commands/removed.php"
        [3]=>
        int(107)
        [4]=>
        array(17) {
          ["customerId"]=>
          string(10) "removed"
          ["year"]=>
```

I'm fully aware of the error itself, but it is definitely an issue that it insists on outputting tens or hundreds of thousands of lines of a var_dump of the Exception object each time it is caught.

Any and all suggestions are welcome!

Sincerely,
Ronnie

[Update]

As i got home, i started a SSH and tried again, for good measure.
The problem is no longer there, no idea why, what or how...

Comment: Don't dump your exception. Instead get the relevant information. Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php), but you can use the methods like `$exception->getMessage()`, `$exception->getLine()`, etc and so on.

Comment: the thing is, I don't dump the exception, on mobile right  now, will add my try catch blocks to question when I get home